Type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object' with for loop
 getAllstudents(stdnt: string){
    let clsss=new Object();
    this.clssservice.getclsss(stdnt)
    .subscribe(
      stndt =>{
        for(let key in stndt ){
          clsss=stdnt[key];
          clsss['$key']=key;


export class Clsss {
    $key!: string; }

error 1:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'. No index signature with
a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.ts
(parameter) stndt string can't be used to index type Object.

error 2:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
'"$key"' can't be used to index type 'Object'. let clsss: Object

I tried to use : string, type of string, key of string, as string but these solutions did not work.

Does this answer your question? 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

What is the return type of clssservice.getclsss?

getclsss(stdntId: string) {
return this.http.get(this.stdnt_url + 'students/'+stdnId+'.json');
}

The issues with the code are as follows.

We have a shadowed property stndt which is set at the top of the function, as well as the subscribe, so you might be getting type issues.
We have to create a separate interface or class, that is for the API call data returned by service (ServiceResponse)
For solving the indexing issues, we can set a index type for the class/interface in typescript like [key: string]: Clsss[keyof Clsss]; where we say that the key is a string and the value will be the properties of the class
Instead of instantiating an Object, just instantiate your class instead (let clsss: Clsss = new Clsss();).

Full Code:
import { Component, Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

export class Clsss {
  [key: string]: Clsss[keyof Clsss];
  $key?: string;
  // Other interface props here!
}

export class ServiceResponse {
  [key: string]: ServiceResponse[keyof ServiceResponse];
  // Other interface props here!
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ClssService {
  getclsss(something: any): Observable<ServiceResponse> {
    return of({}) as Observable<ServiceResponse>;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  clssservice = inject(ClssService);

  getAllstudents(stdnt: string) {
    let clsss: Clsss = new Clsss();
    this.clssservice.getclsss(stdnt).subscribe((stndtResponse: ServiceResponse) => {
      for (let key in stndtResponse) {
        clsss = stndtResponse[key];
        clsss['$key'] = key;
      }
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I have:
export class Clsss {
$key!: string;}
instead of export interface....
It didn't work.

@Asks updated my answer with a working example!
